# Error while importing langchain in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

while trying to import langchain I got the error shown in the image below.
I'm importing the following:

```
from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTSimpleVectorIndex,LLMPredictor, PromptHelper
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
import gradio as gr
import sys, time
import os
```

This was working normally literally two days ago.
How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You do realize that there is no word "errors" in your screenshot right? It said "warnings".  [Go ask the devs](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The problem was that (for some reason), langchain's version was updated to 0.0.305 when I originally used 0.0.148. The problem was solved by downgrading to langchain version 0.0.148.